# Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity The type of namespace Platform does not exist in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin, nuget, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am using `Windows 10` and `Xamarin Studio` I am simply trying to run template and build it without modifications.

I was getting error on missing nuget package and when adding package via nuget didn't work when I added it manually by adding reference to `.dll` from nuget directory main project successfully built however  `*.Droid` project is failing 
on line

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
```

with `The type of namespace Platform does not exist in Xamarin.Forms` which implies that I need another nuget package for `Platform`.

**In which nuget package does this `Xamarin.Forms.Platform` namespace reside?**

Comment: I would suggest right-clicking the solution -> 'Manage NugGet Packages for Solution' -> go to installed packages -> scroll to the bottom and select 'Xamarin.Forms' -> click Manage -> uncheck it from all project, to uninstall it completely (say no to uninstalling dependent packages). Then go back to the 'Online' tab and reinstall it into all projects.

Answer (score 1):

You need the package Xamarin.Android.Support.v(versionNumber). The version number can vary based on your xamarin and target sdk. Check the the Packages folder in the droid project has that. If you don't,  hvaughan3's suggestion will probably fix your issue.